# Deleting approval process steps which is activated once

Tags: approval-process, app

I have one approval process. i have activated it once and deactivated it again. now i want to delete some steps from approval process, but it is not showing any option to delete, but before i have activated it for first time, it was showing the remove option. can i delete steps from approval process which gets activated once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't delete steps from an active approval process. The best you can do is to edit the step so that it always passes on to the next step, by setting the criteria appropriately.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You're stuck modifying that one.  Fortunately this is easily worked around.  Clone the current one, edit the step, activate, and then deactivate the old approval process.