# Remove a few step for approval process

Tags: approval-process, approval-step

I want to remove a few steps in the approval process. You may refer to the images that I attached here. The actual process, once user click return shipment approval/reject button from page 1, page 2 will come out, user can click either yes or no. Then user will go to page 3, then after click on Approve/Reject Record, page 4 will come out.

What I want to do is, once user click on page return shipment approval/reject button from page 1, the user will go to page 4 directly without go to page 2 or 3. Is there any idea on how to do that? [image]
[image][image][image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

first you need to create a custom button field, choose onclick javascript as content source. Then you can paste this code. Change according to your requirement.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/20.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/20.0/apex.js")}

var result = sforce.connection.query("SELECT Id FROM ProcessInstanceWorkitem WHERE processInstance.TargetObjectId='{!objectName__c.Id}'");
var approvals = result.getArray("records");

if(approvals != undefined && approvals.length > 0)
{
var approvalID = approvals[0].Id;
window.open('/p/process/ProcessInstanceWorkitemWizardStageManager?id='+approvalID);
}
else
{
alert("There are no approvals pending.")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"...this is easily worked around. Clone the current one, edit the step, activate, and then deactivate the old approval process". Does it help?

Look at this thread: [Deleting approval process steps which is activated once](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/12578/deleting-approval-process-steps-which-is-activated-once?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

We cannot update(or add new steps) an active approval process. You would need to clone it first and then make changes.

In your case as you want to skip Step 2 and 3, you can delete the approval steps in the cloned version. Also, keep in mind you would need to activate the new version once you are done with the changes.

[image]

Below is the cloned process and you can see 'New Approval Step' now. Also you can edit or delete any approval steps

[image]

Comment: I have try this step, when I go to approval step, it only show me the approval step for how many people who need to approve the form. Not the page. As for now, I only can delete page 2. I remove it from flows. But I dont think it is a good practice.